# django-allauth adapter redirects

Tags: django, django-allauth

I am leveraging django-allauth to provide Google authentication for my property management application. Here is the registration workflow I'm looking for:

> 1. A new manager goes to a registration page with a "Signup With Google" button.
> 2. They click the button and sign into Google.
> 3. On the call back from Google they are presented with a form for additional info.
> 4. When they submit this form their user account and manager profile is created and they are redirected to their company's homepage.

I have attempted to handle this "redirect to company's homepage" through adapters. The problem I am having is that the "get_login_redirect_url" function is executed after the initial Google sign-in, but before the signup form where I collect their work schedule, so I get a DoesNotExist on the adapter redirect because it was called before the managerprofile was created.

What is the proper way to do these redirects?

```
settings.py

ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_FORM_CLASS = 'managers.signup.ManagerProfileSignupForm'
SOCIALACCOUNT_AUTO_SIGNUP = False
SOCIALACCOUNT_ADAPTER = 'managers.adapter.ManagerSocialAccountAdapter'
ACCOUNT_ADAPTER = 'managers.adapter.ManagerAccountAdapter'


adapters.py

class ManagerSocialAccountAdapter(DefaultSocialAccountAdapter):
    def get_connect_redirect_url(self, request, socialaccount):
        return reverse('company_details', args=(request.user.managerprofile.company.pk,))

class ManagerAccountAdapter(DefaultAccountAdapter):
    def get_login_redirect_url(self, request):
        return reverse('company_details', args=(request.user.managerprofile.company.pk,))
```

Comment: did you happen to find a solution for this

Comment: bro did you find the solution

Answer (score 0):

Set the LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL on the settings.py of your application:

I have this value, to redirect to the home page:

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
```

Comment: The issue I have with using the LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL setting is that I can't set this value dynamically. Depending on the user, I may be redirecting them to /companies/1 or /companies/2. I'm assuming that you have to implement an adapter to get this dynamic redirection.

Answer (score 0):

you need to define a decorator which consists of a function which runs before the account is created. Here take a look

```
#imports necessary for decorator call
from allauth.exceptions import ImmediateHttpResponse
from allauth.socialaccount.signals import pre_social_login
from allauth.account.utils import perform_login
from django.dispatch import receiver
from allauth.socialaccount.adapter import DefaultSocialAccountAdapter
from allauth.socialaccount.models import SocialLogin

# defining class to run through authentication
class SocialAccountAdapter(DefaultSocialAccountAdapter):
def pre_social_login(self, request, sociallogin):
    pass

# reciever defining function to hold the account before making it registered
@receiver(pre_social_login)
def link_to_local_user(sender, request, sociallogin, **kwargs):
    socialemail = sociallogin.user.email
    socialuname = socialemail.split('@')[0]
    sociallogin.user.username = socialuname+str(sociallogin.user.pk)

    if User.objects.filter(email=sociallogin.user.email).exists():
        user = User.objects.get(email=sociallogin.user.email)
        if user:
            perform_login(request, user, email_verification='optional')
            raise ImmediateHttpResponse(redirect('homePage'))
    else:
        SocialLogin.save(sociallogin, request, connect=False)
        user = User.objects.get(email=sociallogin.user.email)
        perform_login(request, user, email_verification='optional')
        raise ImmediateHttpResponse(redirect('homePage'))
```

This is assuming you have created a signal over User model instance creation which directly creates a profile model instance also mapping the user. If not, below the model for ManagerProfile, use this:

```
def create_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        <ManagerProfileModel>.objects.create(userID=instance)

 post_save.connect(create_profile, sender=<UserModelWhereMainAccountIsCreated>)
```